# Child component in Angular using input binding is slow when using Google Maps geocoding service

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3, inputbinding

I have a MEAN app using Angular and google.maps.Geocoder() from the Google Maps API. It shows a map and it can search/visualize addresses. I do that in a "map" component and everything works. I have a child "form" component that shows the results. However, it takes a few seconds (sometimes up to 20) before the form component detects changes and displays. How come?

Possible cause:

Maybe the main JS thread is busy with my request, blocking the update to the child component. 
In the browser's network log I see a file called "websocket" (I think a similar one is created when I search) with Time "Pending" and warning "request is not finished yet". I wonder why this is blocking Angular (in particular the update to the child component) and how to avoid that.

More details:

Parent and child communicate through input binding and I am also using ngOnChanges for data exchange. For simplicity I have a test where I just pass from map (parent component) to form (child component) a "formBoolean" boolean. The boolean is displayed in the form after a geocode search but as said, it takes several seconds before that happens.

NB, when I remove the geocoding from the findLocation() callback, the child component is quick in showing the changes in the boolean. That is why I think geocoding is "making angular slow"

---

My simplified code as  shown below should illustrate the problem.

index.html points to maps.googleapis.com with my API key (not shown).

map.component.ts (parent component):

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})

export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    //Here I omit mapProp in the call to Map() above
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement); 
  }

  @ViewChild('gmap') gmapElement: any;
  map: google.maps.Map;
  geocoder: any;
  formChanged: boolean = false;

  findLocation() {  
    if (!this.geocoder) this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    this.geocoder.geocode({
      'address': '1116 S Long Beach Blvd, Compton, CA 90221, USA',
      'componentRestrictions': {country: 'US'} //I use country restriction
      }, (results,  status) => {
        //I omit how I manipulate the results object, place a marker on the map, and pass data to child. 
        //The marker on the map appears immediately. I can console.log results
        //For this example I just pass to the form component the followin boolean:
        this.formChanged = !this.formChanged;
      }

}
```

map.component.html (parent component):

```
<!--For simplicity i just show the button and the binding to the child component--> 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="findLocation()">Search</button>

<app-form [formChanged]="formChanged" [formResult]="formResult"></app-form>
```

form.component.ts (child component):

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { OnChanges, SimpleChanges, SimpleChange } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: '{{formChanged}}',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input('formResult') formResult: Store;
  @Input('formChanged') formChanged: boolean;

  constructor(private storeService: StoreService){}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    console.log('form - ngOnChanges',changes)
  }
}
```

As said, geocoding works but it can take 20 seconds before the child "form" component gets updated and I see the changes in the console

Comment: are you seeing console log in child component after 20 seconds?

Comment: yes, I see the correct output (the current change in boolean and, in my real application , geocoding results) after several seconds. This means that the child component detects changes after some time

Answer (score 1):

You can move the heavy operation which may block main thread 'find Location' to async call using promises.

```
findLocation() {  
    if (!this.geocoder) this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
       this.geocoder.geocode({
         'address': '1116 S Long Beach Blvd, Compton, CA 90221, USA',
         'componentRestrictions': {country: 'US'} //I use country restriction
         }, (results,  status) => {
            //I omit how I manipulate and pass data to child. For this exampl
            just pass the followin boolean:
            this.formChanged = !this.formChanged;
            resolve(true);
          });
     });

}
```

Comment: It does not seem to help but when I move this.formChanged (which simulates the geocoding result to be shown in the form) out of .geocode() but still inside the Promise, the child component gets the input quickly. Now, I see I can also move the geocoding results outside as this.formChanged, but then the child takes time. Please notice that the map immediately shows my searched location based on result (code not shown in the sample. I am adding some notes in the code).